# What exactly is happening under the hood of this code

Tags: javascript

I'm an inquisitive type. I know how to fix the bug but I just want to know the reason why the code below adds twice as fast whenever the div is clicked twice or three times faster when it's clicked three times. Thank you

```
let dumbNum = document.querySelector(".dumbnum")

let num = 0
let x = null 

dumbDiv.addEventListener("click", () =>{
  /*
  if (x !== null){
    clearInterval(x)
  }
  */
  x = setInterval (add, 1000)
})

function add(){
  num++
  dumbNum.textContent = num
}
```

Comment: the event listener should be added to `dumbNum`, right? is the code above a typo or is it correct? Please include the HTML involved so we have a clearer picture (i.e. add a [mre]) - Also by using `setInterval()` you are basically indicating you want to repeat the call to `add` every second (1000ms)

Answer (score 0):

When you click the button, the function calls `setInterval` to call `add`  every second.

If you click it twice, then you've told it to call `add` every second two times.

You haven't told it to *stop* following the previous instruction to call `add` every second.

If you add twice a second then it will be twice as fast as doing it every second.